# How to raise an event when DataGrid.ItemsSource is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid

I am new in WPF, and I am working with DataGrids and I need to know when the property ItemsSource is changed.

For example, I would need that when this instruction is executed an event has to raise:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

Or when a row is added.

I have tried to use this code:

```
CollectionView myCollectionView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myGrid.Items);
((INotifyCollectionChanged)myCollectionView).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(DataGrid_CollectionChanged);
```

But this code works only when the user adds a new row to the collection. Therefore I need a event that be raised when the entire ItemsSource property has any change, either because the entire collection is replaced or because a single row is added.

I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you looked at row_Created event?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`ItemsSource` is a dependency property, so it's easy enough to be notified when the property is changed to something else. You would want to use this in addition to code that you have, not instead of:

In `Window.Loaded` (or similar) you can subscribe like so:

```
var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(DataGrid));
if (dpd != null)
{
    dpd.AddValueChanged(myGrid, ThisIsCalledWhenPropertyIsChanged);
}
```

And have a change handler:

```
private void ThisIsCalledWhenPropertyIsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Whenever the `ItemsSource` Property is set, the `ThisIsCalledWhenPropertyIsChanged` method is called.

You can use this for *any* dependency property you want to be notified about changes.

Comment: Very nice! Exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Allows to create nice control behaviour, if inheriting from standard controls!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that this pattern creates a bad memory leak if not explicitly removed. The source object (`myGrid` in this answer) can never be garbage collected, since the static `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` holds a strong reference to it for the lifetime of the application. [See this question for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682232/how-can-i-fix-the-dependencypropertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-memory-leak-on-at)

Answer (score 21):

Is this any help?

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(
                                    IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        // do something here?
    }

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wnat to detect new row added can try DataGrid's `InitializingNewItem` or `AddingNewItem` Event.

`InitializingNewItem` usage :

[Datagrid auto add item with data of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726930/datagrid-auto-add-item-with-data-of-parent)