# DependencyProperty in DataTemplate not working

Tags: c#, wpf, extension-methods, dependency-properties

I have an issue which is driving me crazy.

I have a dependecyproperty, Uid, in an extensionclass. I this to set a static "language" string (tools:TranslateExtension.Uid="MAINWINDOW_ARTICLES"). I then use the Text="{tools:Translate}" to trigger a lookup for the set language.

This will call ProvideValue method which will set up a binding. When calling this directly from the control, like on the second button below everything works fine. But when I do this from within a DataTemplate the GetUid will return an empty string instead of "MAINWINDOW_ARTICLES". I can't seem to understand why. Any ideas?

A runnable example can be seen below:

```
<Window x:Class="DXSample.MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:tools="clr-namespace:DXSample"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
            <TextBlock tools:TranslateExtension.Uid="MAINWINDOW_ARTICLES" Text="{tools:Translate}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource template}"/>
        <Button Content="{tools:Translate}" tools:TranslateExtension.Uid="MAINWINDOW_ARTICLES"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

[ContentProperty("Parameters")]
public class TranslateExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private DependencyProperty property;
    private DependencyObject target;

    private readonly Collection<BindingBase> parameters = new Collection<BindingBase>();

    public Collection<BindingBase> Parameters
    {
        get { return parameters; }
    }

    private bool IsDataBound
    {
        get { return BindingOperations.IsDataBound(target, property); }
    }

    public static string GetUid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(UidProperty);
    }

    public static void SetUid(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(UidProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UidProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Uid",
                                                                                                typeof(string),
                                                                                                typeof(TranslateExtension),
                                                                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IProvideValueTarget service =
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
        if (service == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("IProvideValueTarget service is unavailable");

        DependencyProperty dependencyProperty = service.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
        if (dependencyProperty == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Target property must be of type DependencyProperty");

        DependencyObject dependencyObject = service.TargetObject as DependencyObject;
        if (dependencyObject == null)
            return this;

        target = dependencyObject;
        property = dependencyProperty;

        BindDictionary();


        return dependencyObject.GetValue(dependencyProperty);
    }

    private void element_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsDataBound)
            BindDictionary();
    }

    private void element_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsDataBound)
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(target, property);
    }

    private void BindDictionary()
    {
        string uid = GetUid(target);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uid))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("UID NULL OR EMPTY");
            return;
        }
        string vid = property.Name;

        Binding binding = new Binding("Dictionary");
        binding.Source = LanguageContext.Instance;
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        //LanguageConverter converter = new LanguageConverter(uid, vid);
        if (parameters.Count == 0)
        {
            //binding.Converter = converter;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(target, property, binding);
        }
        else
        {
            MultiBinding multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
            multiBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            //multiBinding.Converter = converter;
            multiBinding.Bindings.Add(binding);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uid))
            {
                Binding uidBinding = parameters[0] as Binding;
                if (uidBinding == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Uid Binding parameter must be the first, and of type Binding");
            }
            foreach (Binding parameter in parameters)
                multiBinding.Bindings.Add(parameter);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(target, property, multiBinding);
        }
    }
}

public class LanguageContext
{
    static LanguageContext _languageContext;
    public static LanguageContext Instance { get { if (_languageContext == null) _languageContext = new LanguageContext { Dictionary = "test string" }; return _languageContext; } }
    public string Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template scenario, ***markup extension is getting resolved prior of setting UidProperty*** (you can verify that by providing PropertyChangedCallback in UidPropertyIdentifier):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UidProperty = 
  DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Uid", typeof(string),
                                      typeof(TranslateExtension),
                           new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnUidPropertyChanged));

private static void OnUidPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
                                         DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
   // Breakpoint will hit after ProvideValue in case of template.
}
```

That's why in BindDictionary() method, you get value of uid as default value which is String.Empty.

---

Now, for solution somehow you have to ***do binding when UidProperty gets changed*** (even in case UidProperty is binded with some value, you need to update your bindings) which you can do by hooking onto AddValueChanged of dependency property descriptor for target object. But AddValueChanged have some memory leaks problem associated with it (You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23687448/632337) if intereseted).

So, what you can do is use [**PropertyChangeNotifier**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23687448/632337) class to listen to dependency property change and can bind to dictionary like this:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    .....

    DependencyObject dependencyObject = service.TargetObject as DependencyObject;
    if (dependencyObject == null)
        return this;

    PropertyChangeNotifier notifier = new PropertyChangeNotifier(dependencyObject,
                   TranslateExtension.UidProperty);
    notifier.ValueChanged += (s, e) => BindDictionary();

    .......
}
```