# WPF event for DataGrid update

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, datagrid

I have a View with a dataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DARViewer"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataSourceTable,
                                            NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" />
```

I have also 10 buttons and every time that I click on one I call a command that updates the DataSourceTable (is a datatable property in my ViewModel).
The code is working fine, and every time I click on a button my datagrid has the corresponding data.

My problem is that I cannot find an datagrid event that is raised every time the DataSourceTable is changed.

PS. I tried  DARViewer.DataContextChanged(that makes sense) and DARViewer.SourceUpdated but they are not working

The command that is executed by the buttons is:

```
  Private Sub LoadReportExecute(sender)
    Id = sender.DataContext.Id
    ChangeDataSourceTable()
  End Sub

 Public Sub ChangeDataSourceTable()
    DataSourceTable = Nothing
    DataSourceTable = ExecuteCommand(DataSource) 'that just returns a datatable
 End Sub

 Private mdtDataSourceTable As  DataTable
 Public Property DataSourceTable() As DataTable
    Get
        Return mdtDataSourceTable
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DataTable)
        mdtDataSourceTable = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("DataSourceTable")
    End Set
 End Property
```

Comment: Can we see the command called on your button clicks?

Comment: @Shane.C I edited my question to include more code

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how you'd write what i want in vb.net, i think i know how to do it in c#. You can build a CollectionView from DARViewer.items, and attach INotifyCollectionChanged. In C# it would look like this..    CollectionView myCollectionView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myGrid.Items);
    ((INotifyCollectionChanged)myCollectionView).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(DataGrid_CollectionChanged);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ItemsSourceChangedEvent.

For more information look at the answer provided here:

[How to raise an event when DataGrid.ItemsSource is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708806/how-to-raise-an-event-when-datagrid-itemssource-is-changed)

Comment: Ok. Great. I would appreciate some feedback whether it worked or not.

Comment: Your solution works fine. Thank you. I had to adapt the code for VB

Answer (score 0):

After the solution that Marcus provided I'll post the same solution with code for VB.NET just in case someone needs it.

```
 Private Sub ReportView_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim gridItemsSourceDescriptor As DependencyPropertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, GetType(DataGrid))
    gridItemsSourceDescriptor.AddValueChanged(Me.DARViewer, _
                                               New EventHandler(AddressOf OnDataGridItemsSourceChanged))
End Sub


Private Sub OnDataGridItemsSourceChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Code here
End Sub
```